# Image drawing code slower in some hardware configurations on macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-mojave

```
NSImage *tempImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];

NSImage *tempSmallImage = [[NSImage alloc]
      initWithSize:NSMakeSize(MAX_SIDE,
                              (MAX_SIDE /
                               [tempImage size].width) *
                                  [tempImage size].height)];
[tempSmallImage lockFocus];
[tempImage drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, [tempSmallImage size].width,
                                   [tempSmallImage size].height)
               fromRect:NSZeroRect
              operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
               fraction:1.0];
[tempSmallImage unlockFocus];
```

The above code snippet is slower on some random Mac hardware configurations on macOS Mojave, for example:
[image]

It runs fine on older macOS versions.

It also runs fine on macOS Mojave for some device hardware configurations for example:
[image]

Is there some update/changes in Mojave that can be causing this?

Comment: "is slower" and "runs fine" are hard to qualify. You mention Mojave specifically - does the code "run fine" on all systems on early versions? You would do well to provide some data clearly showing the performance difference between systems / OS versions. Have you tried running your code with Instruments to see what's slow? Realistically, `drawInRect:` will not be the most efficient way to scale an image and if you are performance sensitive you should look into alternatives, e.g. CoreGraphics